# Accessing a website with domain from a WAMP localhost

Tags: html, wordpress, server, wamp, ethernet

I am in a dormitory and we are trying to publish a website which all students here can access from LAN. I set WAMP up and created a wordpress website. Now they can access it with typing my ip adress. Any way to connect that website from another device with a domain name? I want it not to require to type ip addresses. I created a virtual host but it works only from the device which is host.

Comment: You would need a DNS Server to do that and that DNS server woudl have to be used by all your dorm mates instead of their current one

Comment: Alternatively if you have a static IP address, you could distribute an amendment to the host file that all your dorm mates would have to add to their HOSTS file